# Why "Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found" even after Installing it in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue

I've been reading answers from all the questions related to `GuzzleHttp\Client` but situation is getting worst. I am trying to send E-mail Updates to all of my Application users using Laravel Queues. I don't know what's wrong but Jobs are failing.

I am properly caching the Exceptions and reporting them to `laravel.log` file. Here is what I am getting when I try to execute queue worker.

```
[2018-03-23 11:43:06] production.ERROR: Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Class 'GuzzleHttp\\Client' not found at /home/polymath/saio/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/TransportManager.php:181)
```

I've already installed `GuzzleHttp\Client` using `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle`. It is successfully installed but still, I am getting the same error.

Even I tried to delete the current application files and clone my whole repository again. Still Facing the same issue. I even tried to clear caches using `php artisan cache:clear` , `php artisan cache:config` and `php artisan clear-compiled`(This made my whole application crash) , `php artisan dump-autoload`.

I can't find what's wrong but that's all logs say.

Comment: Post the code where you are using it. And btw, are you `use`ing it at the top of your file?

Comment: I am not using this package all on my own. I am just trying to send emails. Maybe Laravel needs this package. That's why I installed it.

Comment: Oh, ok, I get it now. Make sure it's in your `composer.json` file. `php artisan cache:config` and `php artisan dump-autoload` don't exist, but that might just be typos. Use `php artisan config:clear` and `composer du`. See if you can [send a simple mail](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail#sending-mail) (without using Queues). Other than that I can't help, sorry

Comment: Yes. I can send a simple mail.

Comment: Have you tried `composer dump-autoload` instead which will update autoload_classmap.php with newly added classes.

Comment: Yes. I just tried `composer dump-autoload` but no, It's still the same.

Comment: Can you test it in one of your controllers? `(new \GuzzleHttp\Client())->get('https://www.google.com')`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you may need an older version of Guzzle to work with Laravel, try using Guzzle 3.x by updating your composer.json like such

`"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~3"`

If you wish you can also try to use `~4` and see if Guzzle 4.x will work for you, remember to run `composer update` and `composer dump-autoload` after updating your composer.json file.

**Update**: This info is based on research since Laravel 4 and may be deprecated for Laravel 5.x

Answer (score 0):

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
```

in your method Add

```
$client = new Client();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).